# How much is A.K. willing to pay for Mirai's nude photos?

Tags: beyond-the-boundary

On two occasions in the *Kyoukai no Kanata* anime franchise, Ayaka disclosed to Mirai how much A.K. (Akihito Kanbara) would pay for her nude photos. The first time was at 16:55 in episode 5 of the main series, but Ayaka's fingers covered most of the pay check so we aren't privy to the modeling fees.

[image: This is the minimum we'd be looking at for your modeling fees]

Then Ayaka bargained again in episode 2 of the Mini Theater, but it wasn't helpful that her voice was censored when she spoke of the modeling fees. However, five 10,000 yen notes were shown onscreen.

[image: I can give you ***** yen]

Are we to take ¥50,000 as the price A.K. is willing to pay for Mirai's nude photos?

Comment: I don't think so, it's probably just a sensible amount of banknotes to depict on screen as a symbol of "money cash dough green $_$ ka-ching" effect

Answer (score 2):

The exact amount was never disclosed. speculation is as far as you can go with that question but id say more than 50k

Comment: 10000 yen, 20000 yen, 30000 yen, 50000 yen by A.K., 100000 yen by Mare. Sold!